# Was the AI Of S.T.A.L.K.E.R.: Shadow of Chernobyl good enough to beat the game on its own?

Tags: videogames, ai

I have heard the claim from various sources that the AI of S.T.A.L.K.E.R: Shadow of Chernobyl, a Ukrainian FPS RPG-ish thing from 2007, had beta AI that was so good that an AI character could be given the goals of going to particular locations, fighting specific enemies, etc, equivalent to that a player would do to beat the game - and succeed. In other words, the AI was good enough to beat the game, and the developers were forced to dial it back in the final release. One example of a website making this claim, from [the TV Tropes page for the game](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/STALKER) (brackets mine):

> Word of God [TV Tropes speak for an interview or similar developer testimony] states the A.I. actually had to be toned down because in early builds, it would regularly and consistently outsmart the player, to the point that the game became outright frustrating - and eventually completely unplayable. The original pre-release A.I. apparently would have been more than capable of beating the game entirely without player intervention if it hadn't been dialed back.

While the AI in the final game is extremely impressive at its best, it's also known to be quite buggy, such that I struggle to imagine it actually being able to beat the entire game. (Of course, maybe this is because of its cut capabilities.) And anyway, even if the AI *was* that powerful, it would have been put up against many opponents with the same AI, so it isn't clear to me that or why the AI put in the shoes of the player would be able to outsmart/outgun the many equivalent AI put in the shoes of the enemy characters. I also know of no explicit citations of the supposed interview, nor have I seen someone unlock the AI's abilities in the code (supposedly the unrestricted AI still exists in the game, simply with many functions disabled) and prove it.

Does anyone know of the interview cited in the above excerpt, or other evidence that the AI was in fact this powerful, or is this merely a rumor or an exaggerated claim of the game's AI abilities?

Comment: Video game AIs are well known for cheating, and being able to do things that player characters can't do, so the idea that a video game could be completed by its own AI doesn't sound all that dubious to me.

Comment: Even if this was possible, wouldn't the opponent ais just as competent as the playing ai?

Comment: @pinegulf This is the primary reason I don't believe it out of hand. It isn't at all clear to me how or why a single hyper-competent video game AI in the role of the player would be able to outsmart and outgun the many equally hyper-competent opponents - especially considering that at the beginning of the game the player would have inferior weapons and armor, giving an even further disadvantage. Even if it *is* cheating, it would need to cheat above and beyond its own exact counterpart to consistently defeat several of itself, or at least it would seem so to me.

Comment: @Benyamin But you're assuming the opponents are hyper-competent.  Typically they are not.

Comment: @F1Krazy A competent AI is inherently going to be cheaty--it will be the equivalent of using a perfect aimbot.  It also has more ability to see the detail than any human possibly could.  It can also do things like perfect shooting on the move.  While many game AIs get cheats like no fog of war you don't need that to have an AI outperform a human.  Unless the opponents have weaknesses that a human can exploit I would expect an AI to outperform at a **tactical** level.  They generally perform abysmally at a **strategic** level.

Comment: @F1Krazy In the case of a first person shooter, an AI can have perfect accuracy and near-instant reflexes. Programming a good shooter AI is easy- programming a bad one is the challenge.

Comment: @LorenPechtel The supposed hyper-competence, that you say they typically do not have, *is* my question. The rumor of which I am skeptical is that the opponents *were* hyper-competent in the beta, so much so that one with goals set to those equivalent to what a player would do to beat the game, would succeed - even though doing so would mean fighting also hyper-competent (as the rumor asserts they must have been) opponents, which is where the idea starts to break down for me since it requires one hyper-competent AI to somehow beat many of itself without any sort of unique advantage.

Comment: @Benyamin In shooters usually the player character is a little beefier and heavier hitting than the opponents. I'm not familiar with this game in particular but in general it doesn't sound too surprising that an AI "player" would be able to beat opponents of similar intelligence.

Comment: This is trivially false because the the game is fundamentally a story the AI has no access to. They are referring to the faction system which is fluff that consists of endlessly spawning opposing groups using a basic "resource ticket system." They wander in specified areas and create an atmosphere of contended spaces. **This is not actually the game per se**. I think they meant that eventually one faction would deplete the resources of the other and dominate the area. I don't actually think a single AI actor could manage to get to the end of the story and "beat the game"

Comment: @Yorik An AI doesn't **need** to know the overlying story in such games.  The opponents will have nerfed controls, the AI "player" always hits, always knows the quickest way out of area of effect weapons and just how far they need to move to do so.  The objectives built into the scenario tell them where to go, they kill anything there, pick up any resupply or macguffins there, then go on to the next point.

Comment: @Yorik Long, long ago I wrote a strategy game where there were secret moves.  Everyone who played the game insisted it was cheating and looking at the secret moves--nope, it simply evaluated every possible objective and looked at how coordinated an attack would be--assume the objective with the highest coordination is the target, counter it if possible.  It could be out-thought, nobody (including me) was able to beat it in a slugging match.

Comment: @LorenPechtel all interesting, but general. This particular game is beaten when you receive one of the multiple endings. The AI simply does not play this game: it is serving a different function, and so the quote that precipitated the question is "trivially false" for this reason. So again, it wasn't designed "to win" in the first place. I will add that I have played this game many times and have enjoyed watching the factions fight it out amongst themselves. It is heavily waypoint driven and the point was to have something for the player to witness. The game succeeds tremendously on atmpsphere

Comment: I played this game extensively. The AI is definitely aim-bot level cheating. Literally 360 no scope snipe you in the face the moment you come out of cover. It's actually not that fun because you have no idea where they are and they can kill you.